# What is the best way to develop cross-platform Java applications with the same core, with git?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, cross-platform

I have developed a Java application. It has a *wide core library*, which is Java 6 compatible and can be used in all platform. Currently the application managed in a single git repository. In the early stage I used AIDE on Android to develop the core. Later I moved to desktop (Eclipse), and I created the desktop GUI (Swing). Now, I want to create the Android GUI on Android with AIDE. Of course, AIDE alerts me, if any Swing or Java 7 classes found (because the desktop GUI) - and vica versa (unfortunately, Java not supports compiler conditions like C/C++).

What is the best method to manage this situation in git?

I have some ideas:

**Branches**: Separated branches for every GUI/platform. I think that this makes merging very difficult.
**Submodule**: This is the most "official". But I have no idea, how can I use it inside an Eclipse project. Thanks in advice for all instructions to solve it.
**Separate repositories**: For the worst case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing git handles, is files in a file system.  Each commit corresponds to a given set of files, and git is really good at handling this.

Git has no special notion of Java projects.  The problems you have must be handled above git level with Java build tools.

Maven is a widely used Java build tool. You may consider restructuring your source code into Maven modules, one for your core functionality, one for the Swing API, and one for the Android frontend.  All these can be in a single git repository.